# XCode 6 iOS Templates

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Hi everyone – I’m working on a new app and just want to get a feel for the type of project I should select from those offered by Xcode6 New project Menu (Master-Detail Application, Page Based Application, Single View Application, Tabbed Application) as the project doesn’t really fit anyone of those and / or aspects of it fit all of them!

So at start up if it is first run the user will be asked a series of questions. There will be only 1 or 2 questions on display at any time so as when they are answered or skipped they will move off to the left as new ones come in from the right. This will occur until all information has been gathered.

The user will then be taken to the main (home) view where various summaries will be shown. Tapping on these will open various sub views and menus.

At each subsequent run the user will be taken directly to the home view.

App is intended to run on iPhone 5/6/6+ & iPad in both orientations.

Any thoughts or suggestions gratefully received – thanks!

Answer (score 0):

None of the templates provide huge differences, other than the initial views provided for you (excluding the "game" template); you are not restricted by the template you choose.

It could be a good idea to create one of each project and see what each of them provide, although they describe pretty well what they provide. For what you want, it sounds like the "Single View Application" would do well, but you can always add tabs, paging, etc. in the future.